# VmPlayer 15.5.6 error on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: vmware, vmware-player

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

VMware Player 15.5.6 build-16341506

Kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic

I installed VmWare Playe anew, then applied the patches from https://github.com/baryonix/vmware-host-modules/tree/fixes-for-5.8

But when I start without the wrapper, I get vmmon error, even though my Secure Boot is disabled (as suggested by this vm-ware article: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146460)

$ /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmplayer

```
Could not open /dev/vmmon: Cannot open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
```

Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.

I figured out that you can manually load the modules and I did

```
$ sudo modprobe -a
```

Now I can at least load my VMs, however the vmnet module seems not to work. Get the error

```
Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network '/dev/vmnet8
```

This seems to be the relevant log output:

```
2021-01-11T15:32:41.807+01:00| vcpu-0| I005: VNET: 'ethernet0' enable link state propagation, lsp.state = 5
2021-01-11T15:32:41.807+01:00| vcpu-0| I005: VNET: MACVNetPortOpenDevice: Ethernet0: can't open vmnet device (No such file or directory)
2021-01-11T15:32:41.807+01:00| vcpu-0| I005: VNET: MACVNetPort_Connect: Ethernet0: can't open data fd
2021-01-11T15:32:41.808+01:00| vcpu-0| I005: Msg_Post: Warning
2021-01-11T15:32:41.808+01:00| vcpu-0| I005: [msg.vnet.connectvnet] Could not connect 'Ethernet0' to virtual network '/dev/vmnet8'. More information can be found in the vmware.log file.
2021-01-11T15:32:41.808+01:00| vcpu-0| I005: [msg.device.startdisconnected] Virtual device 'Ethernet0' will start disconnected.
```

I found a workaround, but it is quite annoying, as indicated [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/9povuy/vmware_could_not_connect_ethernet0_to_virtual/)
Starting up a VM and then:

```
$ sudo modprobe vmnet && sudo vmware-networks --start
```

The below suggested sudo systemctl start vmware-networks.service did not work for me.

Comment: ok apparently you have to do the modprobe only once, after reboot it is still loaded (until you have to apply the patch the next time). still annoying.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare 15.5 obviously has issues with Kernel 5.8.
One solution is to install package `grub-customizer` and set Grub to use Kernel 5.4 as standard - then VMWare will work again.

Cheers,
Wolfram

Comment: Hm I'd rather avoid using an older kernel out of security